# How to find the Laurent series for a function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm trying to understand how to find a Laurent series for a function.

The Laurent series is given by $$f(z) = \sum^\infty_{n =-\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(\epsilon)}{(\epsilon -a)^{n+1}}d\epsilon (z-a)^n$$

However, every example I found seems not to use this formula.

For $$f(z) = \frac{sinz}{z^2}$$ at the origin

How it works? Should I just plug a = 0 then integrate f(z). I'm really not sure how it works.

Comment: Do you happen to know the Maclaurin series for $\sin z$? If so, why don't you just start with that and divide each term by $z^2$? Are you trying to find a more complicated solution?

Comment: I'm wondering what that means $$f(z) = \sum^\infty_{n =-\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(\epsilon)}{(\epsilon -a)^{n+1}}d\epsilon (z-a)^n$$ If no one use it ? If I want to use this formula, how it works?